# How i can integrate mail chimp with shopping cart checkout form

Tags: php, wordpress, mailchimp

Can any body provide me useful links by which i able to integrate mail chimp  with shopping cart  checkout page so that every user passes by checkout page added to mail chimp list to get newsletter.

Comment: use the mailchimp api: http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/

Comment: thanks  but  one more thing that in this i get a file of mail chimp in which i need add the  keys and  need to match the name and mail id type with my form name  and include it to my header  is that  right  want to confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout MailchipAPI there you can create list and add users to it with the help of pre defined functions.

In mailchimp you can divide a list into a number of groups so you can filter your users as per your needs.
http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.1/listinterestgroupadd.func.php

then you can add users to the list.
http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/listsubscribe.func.php

then you can create campaign to send mail to specific group
http:// apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/campaignsendnow.func.php